# Hoard heap corruption

Tags: c++, hoard

When I start up my program linked against my compiled libhoard.dll I get a heap corruption error right at the beginning of the program.  The stack trace points to the PatchMe() method so I have attached a picture to show exactly where it stutters [Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seyDh.png).  The weird part is that if I press continue the exception is handled and the program continues to work.  Not sure if this will cause me issues down the line.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Don't post pictures, and what exactly is `rls_patches` (the exact type, not what it represents)?

Comment: CRT Library entry points but as for the type it is an array of Patch structs which has a large definition.  I can't post it because it is too large